# Creating a Writer monad in Scala

Tags: scala, monads

To learn how to create monads and to learn their internal mechanisms I am trying to implement a version of Writer following this awsome article: [You Could Have Invented Monads!](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)

The problem I'm facing is that I can't use the data structures I created in a for comprehension.

This is a cleaned extract of my code:

```
case class Writer( x: Double, log: String = "  Beginning of log") {
  def flatMap( f: Double => Writer ): Writer = f( x ) match {
    case Writer( fx, msg ) => Writer( fx, log + "\n  " + msg )
  }
  def map( f: Double => Double ): Double = f( x )
}

def outer( x: Double ) = Writer( Math.log( x ), s"Called outer($x)" )
def inner( x: Double ) = Writer( Math.exp( x ), s"Called inner($x)" )

def example( x: Double ): Unit = {
  // This works
  val result = Writer( x ).flatMap {
    y1 => inner(y1).flatMap { y2 => outer(y2) }
  }
  println( result )

  // This works
  val result2 = for { y1 <- Writer(x) } yield {
    for { y2 <- inner( y1 ) } yield {
      for { y3 <- outer( y2 ) } yield y3
    }
  }
  println( result2 )

  // THIS DOESN'T WORK
  val result3 = for {
    y1 <- Writer(x)
    y2 <- inner( y1 )
    y3 <- outer( y2 )
  } yield y3 // Or whatever, it doesn't work
  println( result3 )
}
```

My full code is available here: [Debuggable.scala](https://github.com/ColOfAbRiX/monad-study/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/colofabrix/scala/monadstudy/Debuggable.scala)

1. I understand how a for comprehension gets desugared, my problem is not there.
2. I read several tutorials including: [Writer? I hardly knew her!](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Writer.html)
3. I tried to understand an example of Writer checking out scalaz: [GitHub scalaz WriterT](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.1.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/WriterT.scala) but there's too much noise for me

What I cannot figure out is **what's missing in my code**.
It's like the scalaz implementation returns something that is good in a for comprehension and then you run it with a specific method. But can't find how to do it myself

Comment: Your `.map` should return a `Writer`, not a `Double` for it to be a monad.

Comment: For it to be a monad, it should at least be a functor. For it to be a functor, it should at least have the part of the mapping that maps the objects. In the context of functional programming, it means that there should at least be a type constructor somewhere. I don't see a single type parameter anywhere. In what sense is it supposed to be a monad then?

Comment: I think I spotter my super super mistake. Of course map must return a Writer! It's only the mapping function that returns a double! How silly of me, I spent two days on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can force it to compile:

```
case class Writer(x: Double, log: String = "  Beginning of log") {
  def flatMap(f: Double => Writer): Writer = f(x) match {
    case Writer(fx, msg) => Writer(fx, log + "\n  " + msg)
  }
  def map(f: Double => Double): Writer = Writer(f(x), log)
}

def outer(x: Double) = Writer(Math.log(x), s"Called outer($x)")
def inner(x: Double) = Writer(Math.exp(x), s"Called inner($x)")

def example(x: Double): Unit = {

  val result = Writer(x).flatMap {
    y1 => inner(y1).flatMap { y2 => outer(y2) }
  }
  println(result)

  val result3 = for {
    y1 <- Writer(x)
    y2 <- inner(y1)
    y3 <- outer(y2)
  } yield y3

  println(result3)
}

example(42)
```

prints:

```
Writer(42.0,  Beginning of log
  Called inner(42.0)
  Called outer(1.73927494152050099E18))
Writer(42.0,  Beginning of log
  Called inner(42.0)
  Called outer(1.73927494152050099E18))
```

As already mentioned in the comments, this whole construct is not a monad, it's rather something like "function composition in the monoid of `Double`-endomorphisms with logging". There is no way to make your second example work (because `Writer` is not a `Double`, but your `map` takes only `Double => Double`), so I removed it.

Comment: Thank you, I made a rather obvious and silly mistake overlooking the signature of map

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX The mistake was that you were trying to work with some unnaturally picked types, instead of parameterizing the methods over the types. If you leave the types abstract, then you simply have fewer possibilities to make anything unnatural with them. If you bring this idea to the extreme, you find that you can generate the correct code from the method signature alone, without any comments, without any documentation, and even [without meaningful method (and/or interface) names](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/20-intermediate-scala-exercises/index.html).